# Three.js Scene Switching Performance Issue

Tags: javascript, performance, three.js

I have created a game in three.js which exists of 3 scenes the `GameScene`, `MenuScene` and the `HighScoreScene`. The user can switch between those scenes - When the player is changing the Scene e.g. from the `MenuScene` to the `HighScoreScene` I'm trying to clean up the resources from the old Scene.

But cleaning up the resources seems not to work. 
So here is my code which is getting executed when the user is switching between scenes:

So in the old Scene I have this animation loop:

```
 function cancelAnimation() {
    cancelAnimationFrame(animationFrameId); // EXECUTING WHEN SWITCHING SCENE!!!
 }

function animate() {
    animationFrameId = requestAnimationFrame(animate); // Saving id
    render();
}

function render() {
    renderer.clear();
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

So when switching the scene I unset all click listeners and I'm calling `cancelAnimation`.

Because I'm storing that code for each Scene in an object like `var menuScene = new MenuScene()` I'm also doing this `menuScene = undefined` when switching the scene.

I'm also passing the same instance of `var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();` to the scenes.

This all seems not to help the game is executing more slowly.

What is the proper way to switch between those scenes and clearing up the resources? What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I think a minimal fiddle demonstrating the issue would be beneficial in understanding the problem

Comment: I do not understand what exactly is slow for you. "the game is executing more slowly": more slowly that what?
Also, did you try to look at the **timeline** in Chrome developer tools?

Comment: `renderer.clear()` is not enough, you also need to handle the clearing of your game data. A simplified fiddle would help.